# How to preview eps file in html page?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an html page allowing to select a file for upload.  But before uploading, it displays a preview of the selected file (images of pdf).  It works well but not with files having the extension "eps" (postscript).  Is there a way to preview those files?

Thanks!

Javascript used to preview other files:

function previewImage() {

```
var oFReader = new FileReader();
var wFile = document.getElementById("uploadField").files[0];
var wFileType = wFile.type;

if ( wFileType == 'application/pdf' ) {

    document.getElementById("iframePdf").style.display='';
    document.getElementById("divImgPreview").style.display='none';
    pdffile_url=URL.createObjectURL( wFile );
    $('#uploadPdfPreview').attr('src',pdffile_url);
} else {
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(wFile);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;

    };
    document.getElementById("iframePdf").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("divImgPreview").style.display='';
}
document.getElementById("imgPreviewNotice").style.display='';
```

};

Comment: You don't - you can't view those files in web browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Eps files are not supported by browsers basically. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

So I guess you won't get a preview of eps files to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!